PROBLEBA AL RESTAURAR LOGS TRASANCIONAL
Mens. 4305, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 1
El registro de este conjunto de copia de seguridad empieza en el LSN 13805000007595400001, demasiado reciente para aplicarlo a la base de datos. Se puede restaurar una copia de seguridad de registros anterior, que incluye el LSN 13805000007574900001.
Mens. 3013, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 1
Fin anómalo de RESTORE LOG.
ESTE error me dice, pero hago un backup full del dia anterior y al restaurar el log transancional del dia siguiente me sale este error. Ya lo he hecho con otros backup full y tengo el mismo inconveniente. el unico transancional que me funciona es uno de hace 2 meses que lo tengo de pruebas con un backup full tambien del dia anterior de ese mes.

¿Y cual sería la pregunta?
